# Getting valid url for streetview panorama tiles for user created panoramas with ids starting with CAoSLEFGMVFpcE

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

I'm working on a private library that gets streetview panoramas but the kind of request I'm trying to make to get each individual tile of the equirectangular 360 image is not valid for the kind of panoramas that are uploaded by a user and not google. These panoramas all start with `CAoSLEFGMVFpcE`. Panoramas uploaded by google streetview cars for example work correctly.

I tried inspecting the sources of a user uploaded panorama and found a url that can be used to get the tiles like I need to: `https://lh3.ggpht.com/p/AF1QipNR10bJAxh58s1wHt7-dGQooNiu1RtAdip1uzxq=x5-y2-z4` but the problem is the panorama ID and image ID in this url are not linked in any way I can discern so I'm not sure how to get the separate image ID if it's even possible.

There may be another way to get the tile url from the panorama ID that I'm not aware of since that [this program](https://svd360.istreetview.com/) works for user uploaded panoramas. I've asked the creator how he did it but he is yet to respond.

The current method I'm using is downloading each tile from this url and stitching them together:
`http://maps.google.com/cbk?output=tile&panoid={panoramaID}&zoom={zoom level}&x={x coord on grid}"&y={y coord on grid}`

This results in a 400 bad request error when using any user uploaded panorama IDs but returns the correct image when using a google panorama ID.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for ways to use a service against its legal terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/

> 3.2.4 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.
>
> (a)  No Scraping. Customer will not extract, export, or otherwise scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, **Customer will not: (i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content** outside the services; (ii) **bulk download Google Maps tiles, Street View images**, geocodes, directions, distance matrix results, roads information, places information, elevation values, and time zone details; (iii) copy and save business names, addresses, or user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services.